# Accessing private field from base class

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have an agent that's using the AgentBuilder to intercept via MethodDelegation. I'm currently using @FieldValue on the protected logger field of the base class, but I also need to get the private header field. What's the best way to resolve?

classes to patch:

```java
public class EventImpl extends EventBase {

    @Override
    public String send(String url, String payload) {
        return send(url, payload, String.class);
    }

}

public class EventBase {

    private final Headers header;
    protected final Logger logger;

    // etc
```

The transformer:

```java
public class EventImplTransformer {

    public static void transformClasses(Instrumentation inst) {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new Listener())
                .type(named("com.whatever.EventImpl")
                        .and(not(isInterface())))
                .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
                        .method(hasMethodName("send")
                                .and(takesArguments(String.class, String.class)
                                        .and(returns(String.class))))
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(EventImplTransformer.class)))
                .installOn(inst);

        }

        @RuntimeType
        public static String send(String url, String payload,
                                  @FieldValue("logger") Logger logger,
// doesn’t intercept if included  @FieldValue("header") Headers header,
        @SuperCall Callable<?> callableMethod) throws Exception {
        return "string";
        }
}
```

Tried transforming the base class to change the field to protected.

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(new Listener())
        .type(named("EventBase")
                .and(not(isInterface())))
        .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder
                .field(named("header"))
                .transform(Transformer.ForField.withModifiers(Visibility.PROTECTED)))
        .installOn(inst);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Byte Buddy generates and manipulates byte code which is still processed by the JVM. If it rejects the byte code, it won't be loaded or executed.

A possible work around is deep reflection or changing the modifier on the base class.

Comment: In my AgentBuilder I tried (above) changing the modifier on the base class, but that didn't seem to be reflected in what bytebuddy was seeing (or I did it wrong). I also tried adding a @This to my delegate and within the delegate use reflection to getDeclaredField/getDeclaredFields, both of which returned null/zero fields.

Comment: That is true. Byte Buddy can only look up linked classes from the class loader's class files. You would need to provide a different TypeStrategy that returns the altered type for the changed base class. This is also because the subclass is normally loaded first.

Comment: Any pointers to examples? Still trying to grok some of the docs.

Comment: Is there a way to redefine the base class before the superclass is instantiated to add a getter method for the private field in the base class?

Comment: You can redefine the base class and trigger its redefinition explicitly. After that, you register a new agent with this change being assumed.